Custom swipe-able tabs for android jetpack compose (Material 3)
How can I make or is there any library that I can use to create swipeable custom tabs like in this picture [Songs, Albums, Artists, Genres => Tab],

I know there are already some tabs which is natively built, they are not swipe-able out of the box, but after some work, we can make them swipe-able. But here in this image, the tables look so cool! I need exactly or similar type of tab that I can implement in my jetpack compose app.
Also animate like this would be plus point.


The HorizontalPager is swipeable. You can use its state to also highlight a specifc Tab in a TabRow. I don't see anything here that couldn't be easily done with the built-in composables. That said, such library requests are off-topic in StackOverflow. If you run into any problems when implementing that pager you can ask a new question about a specific problem that you have difficulties to solve. This question right now is way too broad and should be closed.

There actually is a Composable that allows you to place Tabs in a horizontally scrollable row, have a look at ScrollableTabRow.

ScrollableTabRow might not be what they're after. We need to be clear here what the exact intended behavior is. With ScrollableTabRow, only the tab row itself scrolls, you cannot swipe/scroll between tabs [content] (swiping on tab content to change tabs instead of clicking the tabs).

Have a look at the ScrollableTabRow Composable, it might be exactly what you are looking for. You can apply a custom selection indicator in the indicator slot:
@Composable
fun MyComposable() {

    val tabsList = listOf("Songs", "Albums", "Artists", "Genres", "Dates", "Folders")
    var selectedTabIndex by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
    ) {

        ScrollableTabRow(
            selectedTabIndex = selectedTabIndex,
            edgePadding = 0.dp,
            indicator = { tabPositions ->
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[selectedTabIndex])
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(10.dp)
                        .background(
                            MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
                            FilterChipDefaults.shape,
                        )
                ) {}
            }
        ) {
            tabsList.forEachIndexed { tabIndex, tabName ->
                FilterChip(
                    modifier = Modifier.
                    wrapContentSize()
                        .zIndex(2f),
                    selected = false,
                    border = null,
                    onClick = { selectedTabIndex = tabIndex },
                    label = {
                        Text(text = tabName, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
                    }
                )
            }
        }

        // TODO add HorizontalPager with Modifier.weight(1f)
    }
}

Output:

Now, you need to integrate it with a HorizontalPager.

I don't think it will animate while changing tabs but at least it is a cool idea to implement such a tab system. Using chips is a clever idea really.

What exactly do you want to be animated? You did not mention anything like that in your post.

Now I update my post and mention about animation effect.
